# Script can not load because of tag "file:"

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a function which adds an external script to the head of a page. Now I´m writing some Jasmine tests for this function and have the following problem:

When I start the function in the jasmine tests, the script is adding to the header, but there appears an error in the console:

```
GET file:url_of_external_script net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This error happens in my function in the line:

```
headElement.appendChild(oScript);
```

The function alone is working correctly, but in the jasmine tests, the is a problem with adding the script to the head. The strange thing is, that there is the tag "file:" in front of the script url in the error message.

Here is my code:

JS:

```js
function loadScript() {

        var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0); 
        var oScript = document.createElement("script");
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.src = "url_of_external_script";
        headElement.appendChild(oScript);
}
```

Jasmine Test:

```js
describe('loadScript', function () {

    var oScript;

    beforeAll(function () {

        oScript = document.createElement("script");
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.src = 'url_of_external_script';

    });


    afterAll(function () {

        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var script = scripts[scripts.length-1];
        document.head.removeChild(script);
    });


    it('Test if script is loaded into the head', function () {

        loadScript();
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var script = scripts[scripts.length-1];

        console.log(script);
        console.log(script);

        expect(script).toEqual(oScript);
    });
```

Someone an idea, why jasmine have this problem with adding the script correctly to the head? 
By the way, I cannot use jQuery in this example.

Comment: Can you show the actual URL you're using? I suspect that's where the problem lies. For instance if you don't have `http://` at the start, the browser will prepend the current location, and if you open that HTML from disk (as opposed to serving it via localhost), then the environment is `file:///`

Comment: it´s "//f1-eu.readspeaker.com/script/webReader/webReader.js"

Comment: That's what I thought. Without specifying the protocol the browser will use the current environment. Which means it's going to look for a folder on your hard drive called `f1-eu.readspeaker.com` located next to your index.html. Add `http:`, or better, run a local web server and visit your page via `http://localhost`